# HTML and Javascript, Getting the text from multiple checkboxs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have three checkboxs. For example,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" /><label>Car</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" /><label>Truck</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle3" /><label>Squirrel</label>
```

What I am trying to do is get the text from these checkboxs using javascript depending on whether or not the checkbox is checked. For example, if only the first one is checked, then I want to create a string "Car". If the second and third checkboxs are checked, then it should be "Truck, Squirrel". If all three are checked, the string should be "Car, Truck, Squirrel", ect.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $c = $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
   var s = $c.filter(':checked').map(function() {
               return this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML;
           }).get().join();
});
```

In case that you don't want to listen to the change event:

```
function getCSV() {  
   return $('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(':checked').map(function() {
              return this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML;
          }).get().join();
}
```

Comment: Does the .on('change', set the variable only when one of the checkboxs values are changed? If I wanted to write a function to get the string of the values at any given time, how would I do that?

Comment: Yes, the change event should be fired, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this. However, When I call the function, it always returns undefined, no matter what the status of the checkboxs are.

Comment: @user446836 You are welcome, can you reproduce the problem in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: It turns out that my problem was that I wasn't using the <label> tags in my application, your solution works perfectly!!! Thank you. Is there a super easy way to include a space after each comma?

Comment: @user446836 You are welcome, yes, `.join(', ');`

Comment: This is working in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE. Any idea why?

Comment: @user446836 Replace `return this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML;` with `$(this).next().text();`

Comment: Works great in IE now. Can't thank you enough!